# Nuclear Fusion Proton-Proton Chain

Tags: nuclear-physics, stars, fusion, protons

When hydrogen nuclei are able to overcome the coulomb forces, two protons collide. As a result, one of them decays into a neutron and a positron and electron neutrino are emitted. However, isn't mass gained in this scenario because the the sum of the  mass of a proton and neutron is larger than the sum of two protons? I might be missing something completely obvious and may be overthinking this.

Comment: A deuteron is lighter than an unbound proton + neutron.

Answer (score 1):

The mass of the deuteron is *less than* the mass of two protons.

The deuterium atom has [mass excess](https://www.nndc.bnl.gov/wallet/walletintro.html) of 13.14 MeV, while a hydrogen atom has mass excess 7.29 MeV.
([Source](https://www.nndc.bnl.gov/nudat2/wcbyz.jsp?z=1). These values are for neutral atoms, which include the 0.51 MeV electron.)
So in the reaction

$$
\rm p + p \to d + e^+ + \nu_e,
$$

we have an initial mass excess of 13.56 MeV changing to a final of only 13.14 MeV.  The remaining 0.42 MeV is available as extra kinetic energy for the reaction products.

Note also that a free neutron and free proton together are also more massive than the deuteron, by about 2.2 MeV.  That's why the deuteron is stable against dissociation.

Answer (score 0):

To overcome coulomb forces energy has to be provided   to the two protons, and if it is high enough  a proton can change into a neutron ([inverse beta decay](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_beta_decay)).

At higher energies  in proton proton colliders, the higher the energy .the more particles can be created, as in the LHC. [In stars](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Star) the energy is provided by the kinetic energies sof the ions in the plasma. –

[Here is the wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proton%E2%80%93proton_chain_reaction) article :

> In general, proton–proton fusion can occur only if the kinetic energy (i.e. temperature) of the protons is high enough to overcome their mutual electrostatic or Coulomb repulsion